# Deleting multiple ranges of list simultaneously?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

I want to delete from 1 to 4 and 7 to 10 simultaneously.

Is it possible to do that in python or can I only delete one range at a time?

Comment: Consider that contrary idea:  rather than delete unwanted items from an existing list, try adding desired items to a new list.  This can be accomplished with slicing as implied by @RafaelCardoso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example has an alternate way to get the result in one statement, by using slice assignment:

```
my_list[:] = my_list[5:7]
```

However, in the general case, no you can not delete multiple ranges simultaneously.  With Python lists, you can only delete one *slice* at a time.

It is possible with numpy arrays, using [fancy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays).

Answer (score 1):

As per the best of my knowledge, you can not delete two values simultaneously using built-in functions/libraries. However you may achieve that in one liners. One way is to delete the entries using `del` keyword as:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

#        `del` from higher range to lower range
#               v              v
>>> del my_list[6:10], my_list[0:4]
>>> my_list
[5, 6]
```

Comment: Interesting, actually.  I'm not sure whether this counts as one delete or two..  is it possible to make it dynamic?

Comment: @wim: Not sure on how to make it generic. Giving some try

Comment: Actually, it's still two different deletes.  If you swap the order to `del my_list[0:4], my_list[6:10]` you get a different result  :(

Comment: That's true. It does the delete sequentially. That's why I mentioned the comment :P As per the definition of `__del__`, it accepts only one object at a time.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> lst[:] = set(lst).difference(range(1, 5) + range(7, 11))
>>> lst
[5, 6]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
In [42]: L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

In [43]: ranges = [(1,4), (7,10)]

In [44]: for low,high in ranges[::-1]: L[low:high] = []

In [45]: L
Out[45]: [1, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Still the answer to original question is missing *Deleting multiple ranges of list **simultaneously**?* :)

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri: can't actually do that without numpy. This is the closest I can get with pure python

Comment: In other words, one at a time, starting with the last.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: I agree. But I think you should mention that with the answer. PS: Not a down-voter

Comment: you can actually do it in one line with `L[7:10], L[1:4] = [],[]`

Comment: @Copperfield: The answer proposed by *inspectorG4dget* is better as it is more generic

Comment: I don't find it better - that requires your ranges to be sorted and to not have any overlap

Comment: @wim: Solution proposed by cooperfield also requires the objects in sorted order. Comparatively, gadget's answer is better

Comment: You're right.  But it's still deleting one range at a time, and hence it doesn't answer the question